# Displaying validation errors on delegate attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates, simple-form

I have the following (where Venue is a CTI descendant of Actor):

```
class Actor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile, validate: true, autosave: true
end

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  %w{description address website phone}.each do |attr|
    delegate attr.to_sym, "#{attr}=".to_sym, to: :profile!
  end

  def profile!
    actor.profile || actor.build_profile
  end
...
end
```

I'm including the fields for those delegate attributes directly in the Venue form. When one of these attributes fails its validation, all I see is the notification on top, but not the wrapper around the field. I guess this must be because the key in the errors hash of the Venue instance does not quite match the attribute name, being set to `:"actor.profile.website"` instead of just `:website`.

Is there any way I can make these errors display properly?

**EDIT**

Here's the form:

```
<%= simple_form_for @venue do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.input :address, required: true %>
  <%= f.input :phone %>
  <%= f.input :website %>
  <%= f.input :members, collection: [], class: "form_tag" %>
  <%= f.input :tag_list, as: :string, class: "form_tag", hint: t("misc.hint.tag"),
              input_html: { "data-pre" => @venue.tag_list.map {|t| { id: t, name: t }}.to_json } %>
  <%= f.input :description, as: :text, input_html: {rows: 6, cols: 53, class: "form_tag"} %>

  <div class="actions center">
<%= f.submit class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

Comment: what `venue.errors' returns?

Comment: and provide your form view code please

Comment: Added the form. Error messages hash is `@messages={:"actor.profile.website"=>["has a invalid format"]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
module OtherValidation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def delegate_with_validations(*attr_names)
      options = attr_names.extract_options!
      delegate *attr_names, options
      attr_names.each {|a| validate_using(options[:to], a)}
    end      

    def validate_using(target, *args)
      options = args.extract_options!
      args.each do |attr_name|
        class_eval <<-EOV
          dup = #{target}._validators[:#{attr_name}].dup
          validate do
            dup.each do |v|
              validator = v.dup
              validator.attributes.delete(:#{attr_name})
              validator.attributes << :#{options[:to]||attr_name}
              validator.validate(self)
            end
          end
        EOV
      end
    end
  end

end
```

Now in Venue model:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  include OtherValidation
  delegate_with_validations :website, :to => :profile!
end

# venue = Venue.new(:website => nil)
# venue.valid? # Profile validates presence of :website
#=> false
# venue.errors
#=> #<ActiveModel::Errors....., @messages={:website=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

---

Updated:

For any custom attribute:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  include OtherValidation
  attr_accessor: title

  validate_using("Profile", :website, :to => :title)
end

# :website validation behavior constraints to :title attribute

# venue = Venue.new(:title => nil)
# venue.valid? # Profile validates presence of :website
#=> false
# venue.errors
#=> #<ActiveModel::Errors....., @messages={:title=>["can't be blank"]}>
```

config/initializers/other_delegation.rb

```
module OtherValidation
  ...
end

ActiveSupport.on_load :active_record do
  include OtherValidation
end
```

Answer (score 2):

That's right. And the way to correct is to use stuff like that:

```
class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
...
  after_validation do
    if errors.any?
      errors.messages.keys.each do |key|
        errors.messages[key.to_s.gsub(/actor.profile./, "").to_sym] = errors.messages.delete(key)
      end
    end
  end
...
end
```

---

Updated:

**HOWTO Just Wrap Content with div class="field_with_error"**

Notice: Rails wraps fields only if the base object has errors and errors has an appropriate key equal to attribute name (actually *method* name). For nested associated attributes it uses prefixed key (actor.profile.website) according to an associated sequence.

By the way, the common method:

```
<%= field_error_proc.call(content) %>

# where content is any string/symbol stuff.
```

Trigger for errors handling:

```
<%= form_for... do |f| %>
  <% website_field = capture do %>
    <%= f.text_field :website %>
  <% end %>

  <% if f.object.errors[:"actor.profile.website"] %>
    <%= website_field %>
  <% else %>
    <%= field_error_proc.call(website_field) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

A little tedious right? It is better to use Rails' native mechanism of wrapping.

See the next answer.

Comment: Thanks. I'm a little unsure though that it won't break anything else. I was thinking of a solution only affecting input wrapper generation in simple_form.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this stuff with my gem:

```
gem 'delegate_attributes'

class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  delegate_attributes :theme, :errors => :fit, :writer => true, :to => :category
end
```

Option **`:errors => :fit`** declares that i18n translations for errors messages now can be defined under:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        blog:
          attributes:
            theme:
              blank: "Can not be blank"
```

Option **`:writer => true`** delegates writer methods: **`.theme=`**

Answer (score 0):

[Valery](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1222782/valery-kvon)'s answer is working in my case, but won't really work for prefixed delegates. Also, I was looking for a way to isolate the solution so it only affected HTML generation for form fields with errors. Ended up with this (not the cleanest code probably, but seems to do the job):

```
initializers/delegate.rb

module MappedDelegation
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    cattr_reader :delegation_mappings
    @@delegation_mappings ||= {}

    def self.delegate_with_mappings(*methods)
      delegate_without_mappings(*methods)

      options = methods.pop
      prefix, to = options.values_at(:prefix, :to)
      method_prefix = \
        if prefix
          "#{prefix == true ? to : prefix}_"
        else
          ''
        end

      methods.each do |method|
        @@delegation_mappings["#{method_prefix}#{method}"] = to
      end
    end

    self.class_eval do
      class << self
        alias_method_chain :delegate, :mappings
      end
    end
  end
end

initializers/simple_form_delegate_errors.rb

module SimpleForm
  module Components
    module Errors
      def errors
        @errors ||= (errors_on_attribute + errors_on_delegate + errors_on_association).compact
      end

      def errors_on_delegate
        delegated_to = ( object.class.respond_to?(:delegation_mappings) ? object.class.delegation_mappings : {} )[attribute_name.to_s]
        delegated_to ? object.send(delegated_to).errors[attribute_name] : []
      end
    end
  end
end

app/models/venue.rb

class Venue < ActiveRecord::Base
  include MappedDelegation
  ...
```

Comment: Now its clear to me why you have 'actor.profile'.P.S. I'll be back in 1 hour and post an another approach. ok?

Comment: Sure, it's interesting to see a different approach